# S3 by Scaleway via Amazon.S3 nuget package

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core

I would like use Amazon.S3 nuget package for use Scaleway Object Storage (S3 standard) (https://www.scaleway.com/en/object-storage/).

But I get this error : "'The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'fr-par'"

I need to change my region but how?
Thanks

```
    public static async Task UploadFile(FileStream file, string bucket = "default")
    {
         var config = new AmazonS3Config { ServiceURL = endPoint };
        using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(keyId, secretAccessKey, config))
        {

            using (var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    InputStream = file, 
                    Key = file.Name,
                    BucketName = bucket,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                };

                var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storage team member @ Scaleway here.

Thank you for using our service,

unfortunately, the AWS s3 SDK in C# doesn't allow you to customize request region and endpoint, only one is possible.

for the moment, We recommend you to use the MinIO SDK for now (see here: https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet)

nevertheless,

We are aware if this situation and are working on a solution.

### Example

First install the sdk

```sh
dotnet add package Minio --version 3.1.4
```

Then the code

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Minio;
using Minio.Exceptions;
using Minio.DataModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileUploader
{
    class FileUpload
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var minio = new MinioClient(
                    "s3.fr-par.scw.cloud",
                    "SCWXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
                    "fr-par"
                ).WithSSL();

                string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("/app");
                foreach(string fileName in fileEntries) {
                    FileUpload.Run(minio, fileName).Wait();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // File uploader task.
        private async static Task Run(MinioClient minio, string file)
        {
            try
            {
                await minio.PutObjectAsync("my-bucket", Path.GetFileName(file), file, "");
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully uploaded " + file );
            }
            catch (MinioException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Upload Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the workaround. Something still in development? Thanks!

Comment: Hello @glihm the sdk is developped by AWS, not by Scaleway

Comment: Yes yes, but does Scaleway plan to make it's own SDK? :)

Comment: I no longer works for Scaleway, but i don't think so... the vision is to be compliant to the S3 protocol.
i think that the SDK should be patched to accept other S3 services.  (like in python, go,...)

ps: there is a recent issue about this in the SDK https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1502

Comment: awesome I'll take a look at it. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if your bucket region is 'fr-par', you can use EUWest3 endpoint which refers to The EU West (Paris) endpoint.

```
var config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest3,
    ServiceURL = "https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/"
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Seems like amazon as they say in their policy, does not support direct competitor. I always get null to `RegionEndpoint` when setting `ServiceURL` to something that is not amazon.